# How to customize react-native-media-controls?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video

I would like to customize media controls like, Play/Pause icon, its positions, seekbar etc. Is there any possiblity?

Answer (score 1):

You can always fork it and customise it the way you need. Other than that, I don't see any possibility.

I just forked one and customised it the way I needed: https://github.com/criszz77/react-native-media-console

From: https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls